# bash program with two subprograms. How to use getopts in all of them?

Tags: bash

I have a program that we will call A, and two other programs that we will call B and C. Program A simply can runs the other two, and displays help options. B and C are BASH programs that execute other programs in the C language. The basic code of program A is:

```
while getopts "hv" option; do
   case ${option} in
     h) # Call the Help function
       Help
       exit;;
     v) # Call the Version function
       Version
       exit;;
     \?) # Invalid option
       echo "Invalid option. Use flag -h for help."
       exit;;
   esac
done

if [ "$1" = "B" ] ; then
  source <path_to>/B.sh
fi

if [ "$1" = "C" ] ; then
  source <path_to>/C.sh
fi
```

My question is if it is possible to use getopts for specific options when executing B and for other specific options when executing C, in both cases when using A as the main program. For example, if -p is the number of threads we want the programs called by script B to run with:

A B -p 10

Comment: Is `-p 10` an option that `B.sh` processes?

Comment: `bash` doesn't have threads.

Comment: It's not really clear what the issue is here. Are you trying to separate the options that are used by `A` from the options used by `B` and `C`?

Comment: Yes you can use getopts in all. Just make sure to set `OPTIND=0` before the while-getopts loop.

Comment: If you use `getopts` in all the scripts, you need to remove the case that reports an invalid option, since the options that are used by `A` will not be valid for `B` or `C`, and vice versa.

Comment: If `B` or `C` also use `-v` or `-h` they will never get it

Comment: Yes, I am trying to separate the options that are used by `A` from the options used by `B` and `C`. I'm trying the code `OPTIND=0` before the while loop of getopts in program `B`, but it doesn't work. It does not execute the option that I am giving to program `B`.